# One cell multiple updating values, extract only first one

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

how would I extract in excel first value in a given cell,eg A1 that updates constantly generating new values every second.

SaY in cell A1, a value 123, then it changes to 135 a second later, then 145, then 150 etc. Am only interested in the first value 123 within that cell before it changes to 135.

Is there a spreadsheet formula to extract that first value and ignore the rest?

I have tried but failed my attempt.

Comment: How have you tried? What would determine what the "First" value is ?

Comment: Formulas can't do that. You need VBA for that. You need a worksheet change event and check when a empty string gets a none empty string, in that case write the number to a different cell